# Why (historically) do `+[] === 0` and `+{} === NaN` in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, converting `[]` to a number (e.g. `+[]`) gives `0`, while doing the same to `{}` gives `NaN`. This leads to entertaining wats like this:

```
> 2 / []
Infinity
> 2 / {}
NaN
```

Is there a historical reason for this, the same way that there is a historical reason for `typeof null === 'undefined'`? http://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html

Or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a result of how numeric conversion is defined for objects in JavaScript. Roughly:

1. Convert the object `o` to a primitive:

   a. does `o.valueOf()` work?
   b. does `o.toString()` work?
   c. if we still don't have a primitive: type error!
2. Convert the primitive to a number.

For an object, the primitive is usually the string `[object Object]` which has `NaN` as its numerical value. Arrays stringify to the list of its contents, so the numeric value depends on these contents:

- `[]` stringifies to the empty string, which has the numeric value zero.
- `[x]` stringifies to the stringification of `x`. If that can be parsed as a number, this is the numeric value. For example: `+["4"] === 4`.
- The stringification of arrays with more than one element contains a comma and cannot be parsed as a number, therefore their numeric value is NaN.

So this behaviour is in general just a side effect of how parts of the semantics like `toString()` are reused for numeric conversion. This does not look like a conscious design decision, but it is an effective way to quickly implement a dynamically typed language that does what you expect, most of the time. Unfortunately, the results for the numification of arrays happens to be absurd.

Comment: The answer to most questions of this type is basically "JavaScript was designed in roughly two weeks, and that is just way too short a timeframe to think through all the complex interactions, edge cases, and corner cases of the various features". Compared to other languages like Smalltalk (which is of roughly similar complexity), whose design started in the late 60s and whose first public release was Smalltalk-80 V2.0 in 1981. So, the designers of Smalltalk had about as many years time as the designers of JavaScript had days, and they *still* made mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Where is documentation on this algorithm available? I can't seem to find it on MDN.

Comment: @EliRose For this answer I looked at the [`ToNumber` abstract operation in the draft ECMA 262 specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tonumber). MDN is a very good developer-oriented summary of the JS language but not a suitable reference for low-level details of the language :)